# Override Microsoft credentials in BotFramework (serve multiple bots)

Tags: botframework

I want to serve multiple bots from one instance. I tried to override function `OnActionExecutingAsync`, but I don't know how to properly override.

Have this :

```
public class CustomAuthentication : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

and in the messages controller :

```
[CustomAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
```

Where is stored credentials for microsoft account in this actionContext?
Should I edit those parameters in this OnActionExecutingAsync method?

Comment: I think you should edit title of this question as well :)

Comment: Edited. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @JustShadow do you have some idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you check the current implementation of the BotAuthentication attribute? You might find the clues on how to achieve what you are looking https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.NetFramework/BotAuthentication.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334), where the Bot Framework team is showing a sample on how you can configure the `Conversation.Container` with the right `MicrosoftAppCredentials` and use a simple `MultiCredentialProvider` to authenticate multiple `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword`.